# Problema para manipula XML

Tags: php, xml

Estou tentando o seguinte erro ao tentar manipular uma string XML

Este a o XML que estou tentando ler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<integracao>
    <status>2</status>
    <resposta>
        <paginacao>
            <totalItens>2</totalItens>
            <paginaAtual>1</paginaAtual>              
            <registrosPorPagina>10</registrosPorPagina>        
            <ultimaPagina>1</ultimaPagina>
        </paginacao>
        <historico>
            <registro>
                <transacao>19569951</transacao>
                <email></email>
                <valor>2000</valor>        
                <dataEmissao>2014-09-02T12:09:14</dataEmissao>       
                <status>aguardando</status>
                <codigoStatus>1</codigoStatus>
            </registro>
            <registro>
                <transacao>19561474</transacao>
                <email></email>
                <valor>2000</valor> 
                <dataEmissao>2014-09-01T01:09:20</dataEmissao>  
                <status>aguardando</status>
                <codigoStatus>1</codigoStatus>
            </registro>
        </historico>
    </resposta>
</integracao>
```

Este e o erro que aparece

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : XML
>   declaration allowed only at the start of the document in
>   /var/www/gweb/admin/financeiro/chk.php on line 42
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string():  in /var/www/gweb/admin/financeiro/chk.php on line
>   42
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in
>   /var/www/gweb/admin/financeiro/chk.php on line 42

segue o aquivo chk

```
$url = "https://go.gerencianet.com.br/api/historico/xml";
$token = "";

$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <integracao>
            <dataInicial>2013-01-01</dataInicial>
            <dataFinal>2014-12-31</dataFinal>
            <registrosPorPagina>10</registrosPorPagina>
            <pagina>1</pagina>
        </integracao>";

$xml = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $xml);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$data = array("token" => $token, "dados" => $xml);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

  echo $xml2 = "<xmp>".$response."</xmp>";

    echo '<br />';




#define o encoding do cabeçalho para utf-8
@header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
#carrega o arquivo XML e retornando um Objeto
$xml = simplexml_load_string("$xml2");

/*
foreach($xml->livro as $livro)
{
 echo $livro->cod;
#usando o utf8_decode para exibir com acentos
 echo $livro->titulo;
echo $livro->autor;
echo $livro->descricao;
echo $livro->preco;
echo "<br>";

}*/
```

Comment: Coloca o ficheiro chk.php aqui e diz qual é a linha 42 para que possamos ver o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um erro comum quando se tem comentários ou espaços em brancos logo no começo de seu XML. Verifique se existe algo do gênero em seu documento.

Existe esses dois links que apontam soluções mais robustas:

[simplexml_load_file : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588461/simplexml-load-file-xml-declaration-allowed-only-at-the-start-of-the-document)!

[Problem - XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479533/problem-xml-declaration-allowed-only-at-the-start-of-the-document)!

Answer (score 0):

encontrei a solução do problema procure a linha comentada

$url = "https://go.gerencianet.com.br/api/historico/xml";
    $token = "";

```
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <integracao>
            <dataInicial>2013-01-01</dataInicial>
            <dataFinal>2014-12-31</dataFinal>
            <registrosPorPagina>10</registrosPorPagina>
            <pagina>1</pagina>
        </integracao>";

$xml = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $xml);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$data = array("token" => $token, "dados" => $xml);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

//nesta pare apenas peguei a variavel $response e não a $xml2

```
  echo $xml2 = "<xmp>".$response."</xmp>";

    echo '<br />';




#define o encoding do cabeçalho para utf-8
@header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
#carrega o arquivo XML e retornando um Objeto

///apenas troque a variavel nesta linha e tudo funciono perfeitamente

$xml = simplexml_load_string("$response");

/*
foreach($xml->livro as $livro)
{
 echo $livro->cod;
#usando o utf8_decode para exibir com acentos
 echo $livro->titulo;
echo $livro->autor;
echo $livro->descricao;
echo $livro->preco;
echo "<br>";

}*/
```